# Is it possible to use advanced groovy scripts in Java Rest Assured?

Tags: java, groovy, rest-assured

I am creating testing framework based on **Rest Assured** using **Java 6**.

I definitely do not want to use Java6 for parsing JSON responses. I noticed it is possible to use simple **Groovy** scripts inside *path()* method, i.e.

```
String customerName=response.path("transactionAccountGroups.accounts.flatten().find{it.type=='Private Account'}.name");
```

What I was not able to find is the answer if it's also possible to somehow use more advanced Groovy scripts, scripts that cannot be fit into one line? If so, how?

Would really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [JsonPath](http://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.restassured/json-path/2.9.0/com/jayway/restassured/path/json/JsonPath.html) documentation:
*The JsonPath implementation of rest-assured uses a Groovy shell to evaluate expressions.*

Both `path` and `get` accept small Groovy scripts. But instead of using this functions you are free to take the full response and process it with Groovy. There are many ways to integrate Groovy and Java, for example see [Scripting Your Java Application With Groovy](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/scripting-your-java-application-with-groovy/). A good summary has the book [Making Java Groovy](https://www.manning.com/books/making-java-groovy) from Ken Koussen, see Chapter 4. What kind of integration you are choosing depends on your requirements.

Instead of RestAssured (which is for pure JAVA devs) I am using Groovy for testing Java applications. I prefer the test framework [Spock](http://spockframework.org), for example see this [REST test](https://github.com/mpas/spock-rest-api-test/blob/master/src/test/groovy/RestSpecification.groovy).